# Pushing with cloud to device, returning unauthorized

Tags: android, cloud, android-c2dm

I'm testing C2DM and have everything working on the device side. I'm receiving the successful registration and storing the registration id. I've used my gmail account as the sender and I'm now trying to simply test sending a push. I've tried curling and also doing it with a ruby script and whatever I do I keep getting back a 401 error.

What I did:

1. send the registration intent
2. receive the registration id
3. then I requested an auth token for my google account
4. built up a post request to https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send with the above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you signed up to c2dm with your gmail account? See https://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html

You get an "unauthorized" response when the sending account is not authorized by google. Additional note: it took about 20 hours for my account to get approved. So let some time pass.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. I was pasting in the entire response for a request to an auth token, instead of the part starting with `Auth=`. Now it seems to be working, though response looks like: `id=0:1320267945399238%d8a0a49c00000030` Is that normal? I dunno what that means...

Answer (score 0):

You get an unauthorized response when the sending account is not authorized by google.Let the process complete

try out this [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

and note point no : 5 it is push using curl command from command line

first Command will generate your_authenticationid
and second command will push ur data to server

Hope will help u